# Unicode character do not return the correct results

Tags: xpath, unicode, unicode-string, unicode-literals

This command works as expected and return 1 node.

```
# cat myfile.txt
<feed>
<entry>
<author>
<name>Amar joshi</name>
</author>
</entry>
</feed>

# xpath -e "/feed/entry[author/name='Amar joshi']" myfile.txt
Found 1 nodes in myfile.txt:
```

But this does not.

```
<feed>
<entry>
<author>
<name>संतोष गोरे</name>
</author>
</entry>
</feed>

xpath -e "/feed/entry[author/name='संतोष गोरे']"  myfile.txt
```

The file and command are very similar. The unicode text should have no problem.
I have checked it using the utility that I found here...

http://xpather.com/

Comment: You don't say what software you're using for the XPath evaluation. Perhaps more to the point, you don't say what shell you are using, or how it is configured. Command line tools are often not very good at Unicode.

Comment: # Using ubuntu # installed using apt install libxml-xpath-perl # /bin/bash # AWS ec2 instance t4g.small

Comment: Then this is probably a bug in the Perl module [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/release/MANWAR/XML-XPath-1.44/source/examples/xpath). It seems that command-line arguments aren't properly decoded from UTF-8. It might work to run `PERL5OPT=-CA xpath -e ...`.

Comment: Yes. This is correct @nwellnhof Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [probably a bug](https://github.com/manwar/XML-XPath/issues/7) in the Perl module [XML::XPath](https://metacpan.org/release/MANWAR/XML-XPath-1.44/source/examples/xpath) which the `xpath` utility is part of. It seems that command-line arguments aren't properly decoded from UTF-8. It might work to run

```
PERL5OPT=-CA xpath -e "/feed/entry[author/name='संतोष गोरे']"  myfile.txt
```